# When submitting record, I get an HTTP forbidden error

Tags: php

I'm trying to submit or insert record. But when I click on the submit button, I get the following error:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access admin/add-member.php< on this server.
```

Here is the code:

```
<form id="add" class="form-vertical" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?><? if(!empty($_GET['id'])){echo '?id='.$_GET['id']; }?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

Where is the issue?

Comment: `php<` - see this `<`? It shouldn't be there

Comment: @u_mulder not getting you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here problem is

```
<?=
```

Php is not counting this as tag.So you need to enable the short_open_tag =On in php.ini file and than restart the server

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<form id="add" class="form-vertical" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?><?= (!empty($_GET['id']) ? '?id=' . $_GET['id'] : '') ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Also, you should do the following to avoid XSS attacks:

```
<form id="add" class="form-vertical" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?><?= (!empty($_GET['id']) ? '?id=' . htmlentities($_GET['id']) : '') ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I use `htmlentities` to escape the user input.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions set to `add-member.php` . It must be atleast 644 to handle code. Also the `admin` folder needs to have proper permissions.

Comment: You can do it via FTP or the hosting control panel. Which hosting are you using?